# See source of request when get a system error from glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, glassfish-3

I get a IllegalArgumentException: `Request header is too large` from glassfish every now and then. 
I know how to get arround this - need to switch to `POST` request. There is enough good articles about this.

But my problem is that I don't know who sends me this request. 
Is there a way to put more details into this error message?
The IP Address would be enough. 
I guess this error happens before my servlet code is processed. 
So I cannot add the IP address to the error message by my self.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely in this case the control will not even come to the application to apply some logic to know the Remote Address. Only the Server you are using provide these information in logs.

Any server which you are using logs the request in **web access logs**.

By default those log entries will also have the remote address of the client who made the request. If it does not exist, check with the Server team how to configure logging the remote address in the web access logs.

**References:**

- [How to enable access logging in Glassfish](http://bhapca.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-enable-access-logging-in.html)
- [Enabling Http Access log in Glassfish](http://pe-kay.blogspot.in/2011/08/enabling-http-access-log-in-glassfish.html)

Comment: AFAIK by _default_ they won't log IP. Actually that makes sense, since most appservers are behind some proxy/loadbalancer anyways. In my environment I use the %X_Forwarded_for% header, but it depends on the loadbalancer you use.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and put the instance of `HttpServletRequest` inside it in the beginning of request processing (a [servlet `Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) perhaps).

This way, in the error handler, you could obtain the instance of `HttpServletRequest`  from the thread local variable, and - for example - check the IP adress of the sender.

Answer (score 0):

When executing a post or put request assumption is made that there is not limit in data size which is send over the line.

Most web servers have a default configuration of these values. Per default the max-post-size in `glassfish 3` is `8192 bytes` and `glassfish 2.1` is 
`4096 bytes`

Add the following property to http-listener element under `domain.xml` :

```
<property name="maxPostSize" value="">
```

Increase the value if already exists.

Comment: Thanks, for you quick answer. But that was not my question. My question is: How do I found the "naughty" client who sends me get request instead of using post. I need to get his IP adresse or s.t. like this. Is there a way to put that info into the log file?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with enabling access logging:

> `asadmin set configs.config.server-config.http-service.access-logging-enabled=false`

you should also set your logging format with

> `asadmin configs.config.server-config.http-service.access-log.format=XXXX`

hope this helps tracking down the problem